# Просихождение слова "мем"

Tags: этимология

Тут уже обсуждались интернет-мемы. Но мне интересно: откуда произошло само собой "мем"? Что оно означает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

От memory - память и ген - минимальная единица воспроизводимой биологической информации. Термин введен британским биологом Ричардом Докинзом для обозначения минимальной единицы воспроизводимых культурных знаний.

Comment: Если от английского memory, то почему по-английски мем будет meme? Вы пишете про Ричарда Докинза, однако согласно Википедии: «Термин "мем" Докинз придумал, взяв за основу греческое слово μίμημα — "подобие"». (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC)